# "Бежать оттуда(,) сломя голову". Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, запятые

*Любые попытки начать разведку в спорном секторе шельфа Каспийского моря приводят к тому, что Иран поднимает боевую авиацию, и азербайджанцам приходится бежать **оттуда(,)** сломя голову.* Допустимо ли разбивать фразеологизм в данном случае (словом "оттуда")? Нужна ли тут запятая (при наличии слова "оттуда")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

> Примечание 1. Не выделяются запятыми деепричастия с пояснительными словами, представляющие собой цельные выражения, как-то: сложа руки, сломя голову, спустя рукава, затаив дыхание и т. п.
>   (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/151-zap-19-32)

Answer (score 2):

Устойчивым выражением является только оборот "сломя голову", он используется  с разными глаголами, в разных ситуациях, например: **бежать/броситься/ ринуться сломя голову.**

**Сломя голову.** Разг. Неизм. Стремительно, опрометью.

Этот оборот **не обособляется**, но может находиться **в однородных отношениях** с другими обстоятельствами.

Примеры:

Может быть ― весна, распирает от солнца, и просто надо **сломя голову** нестись, ворочать, кричать. [Е. И. Замятин. Север (1918)]

Они пылки, страстны и любят **с азартом, сломя голову, задыхаясь**… [А. П. Чехов. Руководство для желающих жениться (1885)]

Кирилл не стал их дожидаться и побежал **сломя голову, не разбирая пути**. [Д. В. Бавильский. Чужое солнце (2012)]